# When i use pacman -Syu, the package needed is not there for mingw

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw-w64, msys

So i want to download gcc using msys for c++ but my problem is when I use pacman -Syu, it doesn’t show the needed package such as mintty or bash etc. Im very new with these things so this has been making me crazy. Sorry if what i’m saying isn’t clear.

[in case anyone has dealt with similar problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBBWP.jpg)

Comment: Are you using old MSYS, or MSYS2? Did you look at the instructions at https://www.msys2.org/docs/package-management/ ?

Comment: We had a similar question a few days ago. That user had reported this bug: https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/2589